# CSS Pseudo :after Not Working on an href tag

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have create a pseudo css for an a href tag. Before is working normally, but I'm not sure why this is not working anymore. I have try to use chrome inspect element to add the css also it's not readable by the a href tag.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: auto;
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}

.menu-item-has-children>a::after {
  content: '\f067' !important;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  top: -13px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #292929 !important;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-2222" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-2222 child-open" aria-haspopup="true">
  <a href="#">Behandelingen</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu isOpen" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-3495" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2807 current_page_item menu-item-3495"><a href="/overzicht-gezicht/" aria-current="page">Gezicht</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3496"><a href="/overzicht-handen-en-voeten/">Handen en voeten</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3494" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3494"><a href="/overzicht-waxen/">Harsen</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3492" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3492"><a href="/overzicht-ogen/">Ogen</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3491" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3491"><a href="/overzicht-lichaam/">Lichaam</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3493" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3493"><a href="/overzicht-voeding/">Voeding</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

This is only happen on mobile.

Is it something wrong with my code or maybe there's a solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please put your code in the snippet?

Comment: You haven't actually stated what isn't working!

Comment: @Paulie_D the content isn't render. and also if we check on the element there's no ::after::

Comment: Take a look at the linked CSS file，@font-face{ font-family: '???' }

Comment: @多一点点爱 the problem isn't because the link, but it's not render. even I change the font awesome cheat code

Comment: Can you pls share a link or code with css in snippet so that we can work on it and come up with solutions?

Comment: @MinalChauhan I've edit my question and add the snippet. the link is chrisbeautybar.nl and happen only in mobile

Comment: Its working fine for me!

Comment: its working fine for me

Comment: @MinalChauhan but not if you check the website in mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, finally I can find the solution.
I'm not sure why this happen even this working on snippet.

this my working css

```
.menu-item-has-children>a::after {
  content: '\f067' !important;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  top: -13px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #292929 !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

after I add **display: block !important;** it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The code provided works well for me except that if you don't reference FontAwesome css in the head section of your HTML document it won't render as an actual icon. So make sure to reference it. For example, you can put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` in head section and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Hi is that what you want or looking for..!
```

```css
 @font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-display: auto;
    }
    
    .menu-item-has-children a::after {
      content: '\f067' !important;
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      top:0;
      left:5px;
      position:absolute;
      font-size: 10px !important;
      position: relative !important;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #292929 !important;
    }
    ul li.menu-item{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<li id="menu-item-2222" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-2222 child-open" aria-haspopup="true">
  <a href="#">Behandelingen</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu isOpen" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-3495" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2807 current_page_item menu-item-3495"><a href="/overzicht-gezicht/" aria-current="page">Gezicht</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3496"><a href="/overzicht-handen-en-voeten/">Handen en voeten</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3494" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3494"><a href="/overzicht-waxen/">Harsen</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3492" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3492"><a href="/overzicht-ogen/">Ogen</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3491" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3491"><a href="/overzicht-lichaam/">Lichaam</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3493" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3493"><a href="/overzicht-voeding/">Voeding</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

</body>

</html>
```